# How to find unique vectors of a 2d array over a particular axis in a vectorized manner?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy

I have an array of shape `(n,t)` which I'd like to treat as a timeseries of `n-vectors`.

I'd like to know the unique `n-vector` values that exist along the `t-dimension` as well as the associated `t-indices` for each unique vector.  I'm happy to use any reasonable definition of equality (e.g. `numpy.unique` will take floats)

This is easy with a Python loop over `t` but I'm hoping for a vectorized approach.

In some special cases it can be done by collapsing the `n-vectors` into scalars (and using `numpy.unique` on the 1d result), e.g. if you had booleans you could use a vectorized `dot` with the `(2**k)` vector to convert (boolean vectors) to integers, but I'm looking for a fairly general solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the shape of your array was (t, n)--so the data for each n-vector was contiguous in memory--you could create a view of the 2-d array as a 1-d structured array, and then use numpy.unique on this view.

If you can change the storage convention of your array, or if you don't mind making a copy of the transposed array, this could work for you.

Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np

# Demo data.
x = np.array([[1,2,3],
              [2,0,0],
              [1,2,3],
              [3,2,2],
              [2,0,0],
              [2,1,2],
              [3,2,1],
              [2,0,0]])

# View each row as a structure, with field names 'a', 'b' and 'c'.
dt = np.dtype([('a', x.dtype), ('b', x.dtype), ('c', x.dtype)])
y = x.view(dtype=dt).squeeze()

# Now np.unique can be used.  See the `unique` docstring for
# a description of the options.  You might not need `idx` or `inv`.
u, idx, inv = np.unique(y, return_index=True, return_inverse=True)

print("Unique vectors")
print(u)
```

Comment: This looks promising but doesn't quite work for me.  If I run the example code (with dtype -> np.dtype) using numpy version 1.6.2 I get "TypeError: requested sort not available for type" (see below) and when I try to use similar logic in my real problem I get "ValueError: new type not compatible with array" (which I'm trying to track down, but that led me to try the example as-is).

Comment: For some reason array.argsort(kind='mergesort') is not implemented for these types of objects.  kind='quicksort' works fine.  In general I see why it wants the stable sorting of mergesort to handle ties in the indices w/duplicates, but in my case I can just build the indices myself using quicksort and not worry about it being unstable.  Unfortunately I'm still trying to get the view(dtype=dt) to work for my actual data.

Comment: My "new type not compatible" error was because (as you alluded) I need to say "xT = x.transpose().**copy()**" rather than just "xT = x.transpose()".  Secondly, in numpy 1.6.2 unique uses mergesort (rather than quicksort) when you ask it to return indices and the mergesort implementation doesn't like custom dtypes.  To get around this I can make my own copy of unique (which lives in arraysetops.py) which removes the kind=mergesort.  This solves my problem!  Interestingly, for n<64 this code is slower than mapping the vectors to ingegers by dot-ing with a (handmade) vector, but way more general.

Comment: Nice work tracking down the sort method issue.  That's unfortunate, and it seems like an unnecessary limitation (bug?) that structured arrays can't be sorted with the 'mergesort' method.

Comment: It turns out that this has been fixed in the master branch of numpy on github.  So the next release of numpy should allow sorting structured array with kind='mergesort', and therefore `unique` should also work.