# Count number of distinct columns in a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have some simple code and I just want to count the number of distinct columns in the product of two matrices. The code is

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

n = 5
h = 2
M =  np.random.randint(2, size=(h,n))
F = np.matrix(list(itertools.product([0,1],repeat = 5))).transpose()
product = M*F
setofcols = set()
for column in product.T:
    setofcols.add(column)
print len(setofcols)
```

However this gives the wrong answer as all the elements of `setofcols` are different even if the columns were the same. What is the right thing to do?

I will be running this with bigger values of n and h so a solution that uses as little memory as possible would be great.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12983067/how-to-find-unique-vectors-of-a-2d-array-over-a-particular-axis-in-a-vectorized

Comment: Do you mean with columns each containing unique content?

Comment: Use `setofcols.add(repr(column))` Answer is `10`

Comment: @alko I would have to change my code to use arrays for this. I tried F = np.array(list(itertools.product([0,1],repeat = 5))).transpose()  but then I get TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Comment: @marshall why? you can use solution in the thread I provided for matrices as well. or if case you doubt, use np.array(F*M)

Comment: @dawg without specific seed? I got 6 with `len(set(map(repr, (M*F).T)))`

Comment: @alko Oh I see, thanks. dawg's solution works for me as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make yours work by using `repr`:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

n = 5
h = 2
M =  np.random.randint(2, size=(h,n))
F = np.matrix(list(itertools.product([0,1],repeat = 5))).transpose()
product = M*F
setofcols = set()
for column in product.T:
    setofcols.add(repr(column))
print len(setofcols)
print setofcols
```

You can also do this:

```
setofcols={tuple(e.A1) for e in product.T}
```

Where the [A1](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) attribute of a matrix is the 1d base array which can be used as a sequence for `tuple`.